# Java swing. Как сделать глобальное ре-масштабирование? (т.е. чтобы 4px принимались за 1px)

Tags: java, swing, graphics

Доброго времени суток!
Мой рабочий ноутбук имеет маленькие габариты (если линейкой померить экран), но при том имеет бешенное для таких размеров разрешение: 1920х1080. Т.е. на экране умещается ну очень много пикселей.
Беда в том, что, когда я работаю с java swing, всё выводимое на экран ужасно маленькое (скажем на обычных мониторах кнопка 50х20 пикселей будет 5х2 сантиметра, если измерить линейкой, а у меня 2х0.8). Каждый раз менять размеры компонентов, шрифтов и самого окна очень не хочется, а работать как есть тяжело -- портятся глаза.

**Вопрос:** как сделать некоторое глобальное ре-масштабирование так, чтобы swing при прорисовке всё в общем увеличивал. Везде для пикселя, скажем, рисовал 4.

Дополнительно: У меня уже стоит в настройках персонализации windows масштаб 150% от обычного, и все приложения, будь то браузер, скайп, ide, - всё масштабируется, а приложения swing нет. Даже приложения других разработчиков у меня ужасно маленькие. Видимо java на уровне openGL всё рисует измеряя в пикселах и масштабирование от OS-Windows не спасает...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно выполнить следующие действия:

1. Находим jre папку, в bin должны лежать java.exe и javaw.exe
2. Для обоих файлов: ПКМ, свойства
3. Идём во вкладку "Совместимость"
4. Ставим галку "Переопределите режим масштабирования..."
5. В появившемся списке ставим "Система". НЕ НАДО: "Система (Расширенная)"
6. Применить, сохранить, закрыть.

Данное решение должно помочь, если в настройках персонализации windows выставлен масштаб более чем 100%.

Спасибо [zRrr](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190934/zrrr) за помощь в нахождении ответа! Информация взята [отсюда](https://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display).